# kindle fire 4.1.1 Google play services

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

Within the last few days, Amazon updated kindle fire is to include a bunch of new features. Before the update, I had side loaded many of the Google apps, including of course the compulsory Google play services. However, after the update, I could not start the YouTube app whatsoever. I tried many combinations of old versions of the YouTube app, and old versions of the Google play services app, but it still did not work.
I then triedbusing the google play music app, which told me that google play services was not supported on the device. I could not even open Google settings.

Is this a problem that many people are having, or is it just me? Are there any work arounds?

Comment: Did the update "bump" the Android version? Then you might need to re-flash the *corresponding* GApps package to match that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let everyone know, this has now been fixed. I'm not sure when, but the latest versions of Google Play Services and YouTube now work on kindle fire OS 4.1.1.